# throttle with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, throttling

Hello I just started a small node project and have trouble with applyting `throttle` to my `submit` buttons.

I am using a `form` tag and `submit` tag as a button to receive certain data. But some of my users spammed the `submit` button while it was loading and as a result it invoked multiple API calls. I want to prevent this and figured I have to use `throttle`

I am trying to use this module from npm package [throttle-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce)

The explanation it supplied is:

```
import { throttle, debounce } from 'throttle-debounce';

throttle(300, function () {
    // Throttled function
});
```

I first installed the module using `npm install throttle-debounce --save` on my console. Then I added code above in a `script` tag. But I have no idea what to do next. Someone please help.

My code(simplified) currently looks like this:

```
let body1=`
<form action="/client/123" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="return" value="1">              
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<script>
import { throttle, debounce } from 'throttle-debounce';
throttle(300, function () {

});
</script>`
let html = templete.HTML(body1);
response.send(html);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the throttle function to block multiple submits.
I think you should block the submit button after the first submit has been triggered.

Add the `disable` attribute to the submit-button or block it in your javascript with a state like `submitState = 'submitted'` and check if that is not set to submitted.

Comment: is it possible to disable only for few seconds?

Comment: yes with a `setTimeout` function you are able to disable the submit button and after few seconds enable it like `setTimeout(function() { /* Enable submit button or set new state. */ }, 3000);` This callback method will be thrown after 3seconds.